# getting selected RadioButton in another activity

Tags: java, android, sqlite, radio-button

Hi I'm trying to get the selected RadioButton to be displayed in the same position in the update/edit activity. But I did not know how to do this. This is what I have been done. I saved all the String value in SQlite. And getIntent extra in the edit activity. Other field such as EditText can get the extra value. I have read some examples about RadioGroup, is it I have to save the integer selected value from RadioGroup getcheckedradiobuttonid, and if that's the way, how to display the exact value ? please help thank you

```
 public void onClick(View v) {

    switch (v.getId()) {

        case R.id.rb_tiang_besi:

            if (RBTiangBesi.isChecked()) {
                RBTiangBeton.setChecked(false);
                RBTiangKayu.setChecked(false);
                TiangBesi = 1;
                TiangBeton = 0;
                TiangKayu = 0;
            } else {
                RBTiangBesi.setChecked(false);
                TiangBesi = 0;
                TiangBeton = 0;
                TiangKayu = 0;
            }


            break;

        case R.id.rb_tiang_beton:

            if (RBTiangBeton.isChecked()) {
                RBTiangBesi.setChecked(false);
                RBTiangKayu.setChecked(false);
                TiangBeton = 1;
                TiangBesi = 0;
                TiangKayu = 0;
            } else {
                TiangBeton = 0;
                TiangBesi = 0;
                TiangKayu = 0;
            }

            break;

        case R.id.rb_tiang_kayu:

            if (RBTiangKayu.isChecked()) {
                RBTiangBeton.setChecked(false);
                RBTiangBesi.setChecked(false);
                TiangKayu = 1;
                TiangBesi = 0;
                TiangBeton = 0;
            } else {
                TiangKayu = 0;
                TiangBesi = 0;
                TiangBeton = 0;
            }

            break;
      }
```

Save new or update data in the database

```
 if (action_flag.equals("add")) {

        newItemDatabaseID = databaseHandler.saveInspectionMV(details);


        if (newItemDatabaseID != null || !newItemDatabaseID.isEmpty()) {
            Intent detailIntent = new Intent(InspectionMVActivityTabs.this,
                    MainActivity.class);
            detailIntent.putExtra("COL_ID", "" + newItemDatabaseID);
            startActivityForResult(detailIntent, REQUEST_CODE_ADD);


            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Data tersimpan!",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Data tidak tersimpan!",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }


    } else if (action_flag.equals("edit")) {

        boolean flag = databaseHandler.updateInspectionsMV(itemID,
                details);

        if (flag) {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Data terbaharui!",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            finish();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Data gagal terbaharui!",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }


        Intent productIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        finish();
        startActivity(productIntent);

    }
```

Getting value in edit activity

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    context = getActivity();

    itemID = getActivity().getIntent().getStringExtra("COL_ID");
}

 private void setItemContents() {
    if (itemID != null) {
        ItemsDetails details = databaseHandler.getInspectionsMVItemDetailsFromID(itemID);
        editTextNoTiang.setText("" + details.getNoTiang());
        editTextKeterangan.setText("" + details.getketerangan());
        editTextSaran.setText(""+ details.getSaran());




// My problem here how actually the right way to do this please help???
        int selectedId = RBJenisTiang.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
        RBTiangBesi = (RadioButton) view.findViewById(selectedId);
        RBTiangBeton = (RadioButton) view.findViewById(selectedId);
        RBTiangKayu = (RadioButton) view.findViewById(selectedId);

        RBJenisTiang.setSelected(true);




    }

}
```

Comment: Have you tried startActivityForResult ? I'm not getting your question clearly.

Comment: hi Malith Lakshan, thank you. So I want to edit/update the RadioButton. But I want the RadioButton to be loaded and displayed as what I have checked before

Comment: so let say I have 3 radio button, radio button A, B, and C. I checked A and then save. And then when I go to edit/update, I want it to be displayed in A again as what I did before

Comment: Make a radiogroup in your layout and set your radio buttons in it. Then you can pre check a radio button programatically. Check it out here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7743212/radiogroup-how-to-check-programmatically

Comment: Fantastic. Thank you very much Malith Lakshan

Comment: I can not seems get the answer in there?

Comment: I see in your first code you use onClick(View v). If you want to grab a result from a radio button use radioButton.setOnCheckedChangeListener().

Comment: Which should be? the RadioGroup or the each of RadioButtons that I have to make it implement setOnCheckedChangeListener() ?

Comment: as in this example they always mention the RadioGroup ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6440259/how-to-get-the-selected-index-of-a-radiogroup-in-android

Comment: I;m sorry it should be on the radio group.