# How can I set a radio button as checked in RecyclerView by clicking a button in Kotlin?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, kotlin

I desgin a radio button for each item in  RecyclerView with Code B , I hope to click a normal button to check a radio button in RecyclerView which _id of MSetting is equal to a given value.

So I write some code in Code A, but I don't know how to write next step, could you help me ?

In general, I need to check a radio button inside RecyclerView programmatically.

You can't do it by [RadioGroup: How to check programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7743212/radiogroup-how-to-check-programmatically).  All radio buttons inside RecyclerView have the same ID.

```
RadioButton b = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.option1);
b.setChecked(true);
```

**To Faysal Ahmed**

Why need I to do it?

There are a Search button and a edittext control in my APP, I input a id value in edittext control,then I click Search button, the record will be found and the radio button in RecyclerView will be checked automatically!

**Code A**

```
fun SetRadioChecked(id:Long){
        for (i in 0..(backupItemList.size-1)){
            if (backupItemList[i]._id==id){
                //Set the radio button as checked
            }
        }
}
```

**Code B**

```
class CustomAdapter (val backupItemList: List<MSetting>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<CustomAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

    val noRecord=-1
    private var mSelectedItem = noRecord

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): CustomAdapter.ViewHolder {
        val v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.item_recyclerview, parent, false)
        return ViewHolder(v)
    }

    fun getSelectedItem():Int{
        return  mSelectedItem
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: CustomAdapter.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.bindItems(backupItemList[position])
    }

    fun SetRadioChecked(id:Long){
        for (i in 0..(backupItemList.size-1)){
            if (backupItemList[i]._id==id){
                //Set the radio button as checked
            }
        }
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return backupItemList.size
    }

    inner class ViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {

        fun bindItems(aMSetting: MSetting) {

            itemView.tvSubject.text=aMSetting.name
            itemView.tvCreatedDate.text=aMSetting.createdDate.toDateString()
            itemView.tvDescription.text=aMSetting.description

            itemView.radioButton.setOnClickListener {
                mSelectedItem=adapterPosition
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            if(adapterPosition == 0 && mSelectedItem == noRecord) {              
                itemView.radioButton.isChecked = true
                mSelectedItem=adapterPosition
            }
            else {
                itemView.radioButton.isChecked =(adapterPosition == mSelectedItem)
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Actually what you want to do? From the beginning, you want to check the value and select radio button.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [RadioGroup: How to check programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7743212/radiogroup-how-to-check-programmatically)

Comment: To  Zoe : it's not  duplicate of RadioGroup: How to check programmatically, would you please see my modified question

Comment: To  Faysal Ahmed , there is a search button and edittext control,  I input a id value in edittext control,then I click search button, the record will be find, and that radio button in RecyclerView will be checked automatically!