# Android recyclerview onclick radio button

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, layout, radio-button, bind

I am try to setSelected radio button but it doesn't work

I put resource in OnBindHolder

```
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        RecyclerData item = myList.get(position);
        Log.d(TAG, "onBindViewHolder() : item = " + item);
        holder.mRadioButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.radio_btn_selector);
```

And i put performClick() in ViewHolder

```
mRadioButton = view.findViewById(R.id.btn_radio);
mRadioButton.performClick();
mRadioButton.setSelected(!mRadioButton.isSelected());
```

Why does not work?
no log for click

hear is the result.

[radio button does not work do not know why](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VtBhF.png)

Comment: Can you add what Logcat shows, if there is any error message, please add it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7743369/8613355) answer have you ever tried `mRadioButton .setChecked(true);` method?

Comment: i have tried .setChecked(true), and that is not what i look for, but take this seem right, but not fitted.

Comment: Can you open a little bit more about what are you looking for?